# In Clojure how can I pass multiple arguments to a defmethod?

Tags: clojure

I wish to create a multi method which I call like this:

```
(defmethod some-method "some value"
  [ a b ]
  b)
```

: but which selects the function based only on the first paramter 'a'. How can I do this:

```
(defmulti some-method
  WHAT GOES HERE?)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I didn't completely understand your question, but I think you want to
dispatch only on one argument. You can do that like this, I think:

```
user=> (defmulti even-or-odd (fn [x _] (even? x)))
#'user/even-or-odd
user=> (defmethod even-or-odd true [a _] :even)
#<MultiFn clojure.lang.MultiFn@293bdd36>
user=> (defmethod even-or-odd false [a _] :odd)
#<MultiFn clojure.lang.MultiFn@293bdd36>
user=> (even-or-odd 2 3)
:even
user=> (even-or-odd 3 3)
:odd
user=>
```

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean select the function based on the *value* of a?

Then you just need

```
(defmulti some-method (fn [a b] a))
```